# 15 puzzle group theory -

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The 15-puzzle is a sliding puzzle that consists of a frame of numbered square tiles in random order with one tile missing.  The object of the puzzle is to place the tiles in order by making sliding moves that use the empty space.

Question: A man trying to solve a 15 puzzle accidentally drops two pieces. In how many ways can he ﬁt the two pieces back into the three available empty spaces, so that the resulting position can be solved?

I know that the corresponding permutation of the entire puzzle must be even. I also think that it is wise to assume we are in a solvable position for the pieces to be dropped. I just can't figure out how to answer this question.

Comment: Three are even, three odd, maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The answer is there are three ways to put the pieces back that are correct and three ways to put the pieces back that are incorrect.  The reason being that Of all the $16!$ ways to place tiles exactly half will be "good" (solvable) and half will be unsolvable and be switching any two tiles a "good" position will be made bad and a bad position will be made good.  So there are six ways to put the three tiles half of them are good and half are bad.... proving this... is another issue.

Comment: But surely it depends on what the permutations of the resultant puzzle (without the pieces is) so for instance, if it is odd, you want to put the pieces back with one inversion. If it is even you want to put the pieces back with two or no inversions... ?

Comment: If putting the tile 1 in spot A and 2 in spot B results in an even permutation then places tile 2 in spot A and 1 in spot B will result in an odd permutation.  So for every "good" why to place them, switching the tiles, results in a bad way.  And as all are either good (even) or bad (odd).  Exactly have will be even and half will be odd.

Comment: Exactly half wil have one inversion, exactly half will have two or zero.

Comment: okay... I think that I follow. So with the two remaining tiles, we have six ways to put them into the game, in which three will result in an odd permutation and the other three an even permutation. Therefore, there are always three correct ways to put the back, and one chooses an even or an odd permutation to correspond to the parity of the graph without the dropped tiles to make it even?

Comment: Even more basic.  For any: tile 1 in space x, and tile 2 in space y, will be either an even or odd permutation.  That one way is directly corespondent with tile 2 in space x, and tile 1 in space y which will be the exact opposite paritity.  So given an situation the number of even permutations will be in 1-1 correspondence with odd permutations.  You could drop 52 tiles of a 365 puzzle and half the ways to put them back will be good and have will be bad.

Comment: How do you define even and odd permutations, if two tiles are missing? In general you won't even have a permutation.

Comment: I thought that you could just disregard those tiles?

Answer (score 1):

Say the three open squares are A, B, and C, and the two pieces that fell were the ones that were in squares A and B.

he can put the two pieces back in 6 ways:

AB- (piece that was in A goes back in A, and piece that was in B goes back in B)

A-B (piece that was in A goes back in A, but piece that was in B goes back in C)

BA-

B-A

-AB

-BA

Now, clearly AB- is solvable, since that's how the pieces were in originally, while BA- is not, since that one is one inversion from a solvable state. But what about the others? Well, A-B could be solvable (e.g. Imagine that C was right next to B). But if A-B is solvable, then B-A is one inversion away from that, and therefore unsolvable. In other words, exactly one of A-B and B-A is solvable ... we just don't know which one. Likewise, exactly one of -AB and -BA is solvable. In fact, we don't even need to assume that the board was solvable *before* the two pieces fell ... all we need is that out of AB- and BA- exactly one is solvable. Therefore, out of these 6 possibilities, 3 will be solvable.

Comment: but surely this doesn't not hold true if the puzzle without the tiles is of odd parity?

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Yeah, I just realized this myself ...

Comment: still for the reasons in the comments there are still three solutions

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale yeah, it's pretty obvious the answer must be three ... It's just that the reasoning is tricky ...

Comment: Beat me to it.  +1

Comment: @CatherineDrysdale Updated my answer ...

Comment: "It's just that the reasoning is tricky"  Really?  If 1 to x and 2 to y works or doesn't work then 1 to y and 2 to x won't or will  For every way we have to put tiles back we will have another exactly the same but with the two tiles switched.  Seems preety straightforward to me.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, just figured that out myself and updated my answer to reflect that.